Почему операция с итерацией вперед выполняется быстрее чем в обратную сторону?
Я пишу что то вроде клеточного автомата с симуляцией эволюции. В моем коде есть функция move, которая двигает клетки по полю.
int clamp(int a)
{
    if (a > 1199) return 1199;
    if (a < 0) return 0;
    else return a;
}

void move(shared_ptr<Cell>(&Cells)[1200][1200], int direction)
{   
    if (energy >= 10)
    {
        int offset_x = 0;
        int offset_y = 0;
        if (direction == 0) { offset_x = -1; }
        if (direction == 2) { offset_x = 1; }
        if (direction == 3) { offset_y = -1; }
        if (direction == 1) { offset_y = 1; }

        if (Cells[clamp(pos[0] + offset_x)][clamp(pos[1] + offset_y)] -> age == -1)
        {   
            Cells[clamp(pos[0] + offset_x)][clamp(pos[1] + offset_y)] = Cells[clamp(pos[0])][clamp(pos[1])];
            Cells[clamp(pos[0])][clamp(pos[1])] = make_shared<Cell>(0, pos[0], pos[1]);
            pos[0] = clamp(pos[0] + offset_x);
            pos[1] = clamp(pos[1] + offset_y);
            energy -= 10;
        }
    }
}

В качестве аргумента direction_index выступает сгенерированная неким подобием нейронки цифра от 0 до 3 включительно. В ситуациях, где на вход функции подаются цифры 0 и 3, то есть где хоть одно из значений смещения по столбцам и рядам двумерного массива становится отрицательным, программа выполняется в десятки раз медленнене чем в случае движения вперед по списку с клетками. С чем это может быть связано?

Возможно это связано с предвыборкой памяти (preloading cpu cache). Обычно, когда вы обращаетесь к данным, которых еще нет в кэше, то кроме транзакции к памяти для чтения этих данных, аппаратура вырабатывает еще несколько (2 или 3) транзакций для чтения следующих строк (обычно по 64 байта) кэша

Учитывая, что внутри функции есть освобождение и захват памяти, preloading cpu cache кажется слишком тонким эффектом, чтобы дать замедление "десятки раз медленнене". Возможно, для разных направлений, функция вызывается разное число раз, из-за специфики данных в матрице.

@AlexF Cell в данном случае - базовый класс для производных от него по типу хищника травоядного и падальщика. Умные указатели использую так как насколько я понял из c++ Primer это стандартный способ создавать массивы с потомками некоторго класса. Со временем осознал что колличество указателей у меня константно и использовать обычные укзаатели будет быстрее и проще, но я планирую переделывать программу целиком, так что это вероятно будет в следующей реализации
